# T-SQL How to join to multiple tables depending on value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, left-join

So I have some complicated production tables. What it comes down to, however, is that I'd like to be able to join to multiple tables depending on the where the value is that I'm seeking. Specifically, say I have an employee ID, "JHDOE", and I want to join it to the table where I can get that employee's name. The main table for employees is "Table A":
[image: Table A]

Notice that the field ID_2 does NOT have the value "JHDOE". Instead, it has "DOEJH". Well, there is another table that actually has the value I'm seeking, "Table B":

[image: Table B]

In this table, we do see "JHDOE" so at first I tried something like this:

```
from TableStart as start
left join TableB as b on
            case
                when start.EMP_ID like '[0-9]%'
                then b.ID
                else b.ID_2
            end = start.EMP_ID
```

But this created other problems. So what I'd like to do is do something like join to EITHER table, or at least something to the same effect. One method I tried was this:

```
from TableStart as start
left join (select a.Name, a.ID, a.ID_2
           from TableA as a
           union
           select b.Name, b.ID, b.ID_2
           from TableB as b) names on
            case
                when start.EMP_ID like '[0-9]%'
                then names.ID
                else names.ID_2
            end = start.EMP_ID
```

The result set for the union looks like this:

[image: Union Result Set]

On my production data, this same scenario resulted in a blank. I suppose it doesn't know which row to join to? So I think I need to do something like pivot the rows into columns and then do an OR... but I'm not sure. I would be greatly appreciative of any guidance or instruction.

Comment: Are you looking for answer in T-SQL or Linq ?

Comment: I am looking for an answer in T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a CASE in the join I think an IN operator would work. That will function as an OR (EMP_ID = ID or EMP_ID = ID_2). And if you LEFT JOIN from TableStart to both TableA and TableB and use the COALESCE function with each column from TableA and TableB you will get the first non-null value.

This assumes that if both TableA and TableB have a match for TableStart you are fine with taking the first non-null value which could result in a mixture of values from TableA and TableB if TableA has some null values.

```
select 
  start.*
, coalesce (a.Name, b.Name) as [Name]
, coalesce (a.ID, b.ID)     as [ID]
, coalesce (a.ID_2, b.ID_2) as [ID_2]
from TableStart as start
left join TableA as a on start.EMP_ID in (a.ID, a.ID_2)
left join TableB as b on start.EMP_ID in (b.ID, b.ID_2)
```

Here is the full [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a3e0f64b362bf107d54699bfe3c27870).

Comment: Thanks, Isaac. This didn't quite work for what I needed (too many possible results I think) but what I ended up doing is keeping the left join and whenever a NULL appeared, I used ISNULL to get the ID_2. Fortunately, one can infer the employee based on ID_2 without too much trouble.